# How to Make a Text Input box become non-writable when a checkbox is clicked?

Tags: javascript, input

On my website, users can enter their name, but they can also click a check box in order to post anonymously. I'm not that good with JS, so can anyone guide me in making it so when the check box is clicked the user becomes unable to write in the name input field? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
function toggleReadonly(element) {
    var inputName = document.getElementById('inputName');
    if(element.checked) {
        inputName.setAttribute('readonly', true);
    }
    else {
        inputName.removeAttribute('readonly');
    }
}

<input type='text' id="inputName"/>
<input type='checkbox' onclick='toggleReadonly(this)'/>
```

You can see it working **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/mCtfR/1/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You want to toggle the `'disabled'` property of the `input` element, e.g.

```
var input = document.getElementById('theInput')
input.disabled = !input.disabled;
```

Add that in a function to the change event of the `checkbox` and you should be good to go.

EDIT: I whipped it up in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbGHz/) to make sure it would work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, for some reason it isn't working when I put it on my page? Do you have any idea why?

Comment: What did you put on your page?

Comment: I put the JS code you listed in the jsFiddle in between <script> tags, than added the id's to the input tags.